# Unable to push the method to the rabbitmq queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabbitmq, amqp

I am working on rabbitmq and trying to push a method to a queue from my ruby on rails app and I am running a server side ruby script to read the queue and execute the method which is send in the payload. Here is my client side code.

```
module Rabbitesh
  require 'amqp'
  #debugger
  def self.call_rabbits(payload,queue_name)
    AMQP.start(:host => "localhost") do |connection|
      channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
      queue = channel.queue(queue_name)
      channel.default_exchange.publish(payload, :routing_key => queue.name)
      #EM.add_timer(0.01) do
        connection.close do

        #end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This is now I call the Rabbitmq function

```
Rabbitesh::call_rabbits(obj,"welcome_mail")
```

where "welcome_mail" is the queue_name

This is the server side script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'amqp'
require 'daemons'

options = { :backtrace => true, :dir => '.', :log_output => true}

Daemons.run_proc('raabbitmq_daemon',options) do
  AMQP.start(:host => "localhost") do |connection|
    channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    queue = channel.queue("welcome_mail")

    Signal.trap("INT") do
      connection.close do
        EM.stop { exit }
      end
    end

    puts " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"

    queue.subscribe do |body|
      UserMailers.welcome_organic(body).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is when my rails app calls the rabbitmq function the console stops there saying "updating client properties" and though I will be running my server side ruby script, it will not read the queue and take execute the process. I am not able to understand whats wrong with the code, kindly help me out.